# Which versions of MSVC support __func__ when compiling C code?

Tags: visual-c++

For older MSVC versions `__func__` needed to be defined, eg:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#   define __func__ __FUNCTION__
#endif
```

From reading the docs, this seems to be supported now.

Which version of MSVC first introduced this?

---

*Note, I don't have MSVC so this question is to avoid breaking code for others.*

Comment: VS 2015 or later supports ``__func__`` for C++11 code.

Comment: And for C code?